# How to integrate two disparate websites with a common login without exposing passwords?

Tags: security, authentication, single-sign-on

I have a website, call it "Site One" in which users create accounts with a username and password. For security, I then salt and hash the user's password and store it in a SQL Database. It all works great.

Now enter "Site Two" which is written by a different company. We would like to integrate the two apps so that if a user is logged into Site Two, they would be able to:

1. Create an account on Site one through a Web API.
2. Have a one click seamless login from Site Two back to Site One.

Is this achievable without Site Two being able to Store and Retrieve the password from the user account that they created?  The only way I can think of this working is that after Site Two makes the WebAPI call to Site One to create an account, Site Two would have to be able to store the password which was used to create that account in the first place, thus opening a big security hole in case someone was able to get a hold of the password.

I supposed as an added security layer, I could prevent that password from being used except when the login info is posted from a known IP address, but I'm not sure if this is enough protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementing single sign-on (SSO) using SAML 2.0, where Site One is an Identity Provider (IdP) a Service Provider (SP), and Site Two is a Service Service Provider.

Assuming that users will visit Site Two first, then you would want to implement Service Provider initiated SSO on Site Two. The effect of this would be that whenever a user requests a secured resource on Site Two, the user would be directed to Site One, which would prompt them for the user for a username and password. Once authenticated, the user would be re-directed back to Site Two to access the secured resource that the user originally requested.

An overview taken from [OASIS SAML 2.0 documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.html#5.1.1.Introduction%7Coutline):

[image: SP-Initiated SSO: Redirect/POST Bindings]

> 1. The user attempts to access a resource on sp.example.com. The user does not have a valid logon session (i.e. security context) on this site. The SP saves the requested resource URL in local state information that can be saved across the web SSO exchange.
> 2. The SP sends an HTTP redirect response to the browser (HTTP status 302 or 303). The Location HTTP header contains the destination URI of the Sign-On Service at the identity provider.
> 3. The Single Sign-On Service determines whether the user has an existing logon security context at the identity provider that meets the default or requested authentication policy requirements. If not, the IdP interacts with the browser to challenge the user to provide valid credentials.
> 4. The user provides valid credentials and a local logon security context is created for the user at the IdP.
> 5. The IdP Single Sign-On Service builds a SAML assertion representing the user's logon security context. The Single Sign-On Service sends the HTML form back to the browser in the HTTP response.
> 6. The browser, due either to a user action or execution of an “auto-submit” script, issues an HTTP POST request to send the form to the SP's Assertion Consumer Service.
> 7. An access check is made to establish whether the user has the correct authorization to access the resource. If the access check passes, the resource is then returned to the browser.